# Unable to change the location of Installation in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

How to change the installation location in VS2017, currently its showing in the gray shade (Read-only) like:

[image]

Comment: You can't, unless it's a fresh installation.

Comment: Do I need to uninstall and re-install?

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale, Would you please share us the latest information after you view Sara's suggestions?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I have un-installed the VS and then re-installed and have cleared some storage from C then its installed without an issue

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if Sara's suggestion is helpful for you, you could accept it as the answer. Or you could also share your solution and mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members, and I could close this case for you. Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: yes as I have also cleared the folder data which suggested by Sara

Answer (score 3):

Please check this doc: [Change the installation locations in VS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/change-installation-locations?view=vs-2017) and those locations is set with your first installation and cannot be changed later from the installer UI. If you just want to move the download cache, you can use [command-line parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) and for others, please try to clean up the installed VS like the following and re-install it:

•   See if you have this file on your machine: "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe"

•   If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a -full param:
InstallCleanup.exe -full
•   If not, please manually delete the "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer” folder

•   Relaunch the newly downloaded vs_enterprise.exe (or vs_professional.exe or vs_community.exe…)

•   Allow the first step to install the installer

•   Once the installer comes up and you can see workload choices (.net desktop and the like), close it

•   Go launch the same InstallCleanup.exe to clean up old build of VS

•   Then re-run the VS installer to install

BTW, this method can reduce the installation footprint on your system drive but there are some tools and SDKs that have different rules on where they can be are installed. These tools and SDKs will still be installed on your system drive even if you choose another location.